# Mathematical models for personal finance decisions

Tags: modeling, reference-request

I'm doing some bibliographic research on mathematical models for personal finance decisions. I should like to ask whether you know any of them, because the research that I did on Google Scholar haven't produced anything. To be precise, I looked up the words combinations *"personal finance decision" "mathematical model"*, *"personal finance decision" game*, *"personal finance" "nash equilibria"*, *"personal finance" "nash equilibrium"* and *"personal finance" "mathematical model"*.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would be a 'personal finance decision' in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean individual economic decisions such as saving, pension, purchasing, and risk taking etc. and all the underlying rational and irrational behaviours. These fall under the behavioural economics and phrases such as individual economic decision and behaviour economics should produce a long list. Here is an introductory text that contains the necessary terminology and some references:

https://www.aqa.org.uk/resources/economics/as-and-a-level/economics/teach/teachers-guide-individual-economic-decision-making

Hope this helps!